# Excel, count unique values if criteria - HUGE data set

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

problem i have 300.000 entries

```
Colum A = YEAR
Colum B = month
Colum C = customer number

G5 to G13 = criteria
```

I want to count how many unique customers pr. year - I tried using an array formula - but that is no good on such a huge data set... i guess...

formula used

```
=SUM(--(FREKVENS(HVIS(A:A=G5;SAMMENLIGN(C:C;C:C;0));RÆKKE(B:B)-RÆKKE(C1)+1)>0))
```

or in english:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A:A=G5,MATCH(C:C,C:C,0)),ROW(B:B)-ROW(C1)+1)>0))
```

This works fine just fine if i have a small data set - but with my dataset it just starts to calculate and then stay at 100% cpu for hours

So what do I do ?

Comment: You might want to consider moving this sort of dataset to a database technology and get the DB server to do the heavy lifting on calculations.

Comment: Could you use `SUBTOTAL`?

Answer (score 0):

Using DB is not an option - as others should be able to use this :(

Solution i made is not pretty but it works

1) Make a copy of all customers and remove duplicates
2) use VLOOKUP to find year (since the list is sorted reversed it will get the first time i see a customer)
3) now i do a simple countif with the year as criteria.

Not pretty especially because i had to copy 2) down 465.451 rows

Comment: Using a DB might not be an option, but it is the right (tm) way. Excel has grown a lot from a simple spreadsheet to a huge much capable program, but with these kinds of data you really want a full database or at leats a light db such as access.  (Writes the person who recently hit the 1.8mil, lines in excel limit...)